# Only enumerate if there is no exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, enumeration

I have code like this:

```
for index, img in enumerate(soup.find_all("img")):
    try:
        print(f"[{index}] {img['data-src']}")
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

As you see, I must use a try-except clause as some images I am searching through do not have the data-src key (I am unable to narrow into specific divs that contain only images with data-src).

I only want the enumerate to increment if there is no exception. How can this be done?

Comment: The answer seems pretty good to me. If you like it, accept it by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First filter only the `img`s that **have** the `data-src` attribute, **then** enumerate:

```
for index, img in enumerate(x for x in soup.find_all("img") if 'data-src' in x):
    print(f"[{index}] {img['data-src']}")
```

Comment: thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of this haha!